# PyMongo and Mongodb Scalability With Very Large Datasets

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo, crud

I am chugging through some issues with mongo db Scalability in my Crud API. The intent of the API is to write/read a db storing some lab data. Each measurement is essentially a document, but each measurement can be very large as there are pre/post loggers as well as the actual measurements. We also collect quite large datasets (15000+ row excel table, 650+ cols.) I create a unique _ids for each document to avoid the server side having to reindex and create the _id key.

```
{ "_id" : "7CEXTIA5KUGLRQLIH62T", <some 60 k/v pairs> "blockName" : "e particular measurement field", "blockValue" : 1, "job" : "job", "project" : "project", "__ids__" : "2TMOHO74WQ7CYPWM32JD", "testname" : "VOLUME_DATA" }
```

So basically each document contains the pre/post loggers and a measurement. In a table form these measurements would be columns.

I am using the backend as a flask API and its suing PyMongo to communicate with the MongoDB Server.

**Where the overhead is:**

The overhead is occurring when I unpack the cursor. I am collecting each document in an array and converting it to a data frame. This is what is taking the bulk of the time. Here is the data handler:

```
res = collection.find(filt)

for x in collection.find(filt):
    qData.append(x)
    
ret_data = post_process.convert_data_frame(qData)  
 
return {
    "retrieved": ret_data,
    "status":"OK",
    "code":"200",
    "rows": ret_data.shape[0],
    "cols": ret_data.shape[1]
}
```

Here is my timing. Basically the query is very fast, and the conversion to a dataframe is not particularly slow.

```
[Query Time :0.0]
[Array length: 381656]
[Collection into Array Time :179.22241806983948]
[Array to DF Time :11.4875328540802]
```

Is there a fast way to collect each element. Is it the size of each document (basically a dict with 65+ keys) effecting the collection of this data into an array?

Basically, I cant think of a more efficient method of unpacking this cursor to an array for processing.

Would it be better to batch the queries and build and array with each batch? But this again would require me to iterate the cursor....

Comment: Bear in mind `find` does nothing except to initiate the cursor. It doesn't even hit the database. Do you need all 65 fields?; if not use a projection parameter in your `find` to limit the amount of data being returned.

Comment: Thanks @BellyBuster . Yeah i understand the function of find.... Unfortunately this is likely the case.... I would love to project but this isn't practical in the situation. Alternatively I can add a knob which requests for what to be projected - however I need to make this as robust as possible since it will be used org wide for data processing